# gnuplot doesn't work through ssh command

Tags: linux, ssh, plot, gnuplot

So I have a csv, and I have a plt file. I run `gnuplot plt-file.plt` and a png is born.

But if I run `ssh sameuser@samemachine 'gnuplot plt-file.plt'` I get a pngcario error.

The csv: sar.csv

```
time,               average io writes 
4/15/2014 22:28,    6.040546875
4/15/2014 22:28,    7.943100586
4/15/2014 22:29,    8.686162109
4/15/2014 22:29,    7.693891602
4/15/2014 22:30,    8.579804688
4/15/2014 22:30,    7.900537109
```

The plt:

```
clear
reset
print "sar"
set terminal pngcairo transparent enhanced font "arial,25" fontscale 1.0 size 1920, 1080
set key outside bottom center box title "sar" enhanced
set key maxrows 4
set key font ",25" spacing 1 samplen 2.9 width 2 height 1
set xlabel "Time (hours)" font ",25"
set ylabel "Utilization (%)" font ",25"

set output "./sar.png"
set title "sar" font ",35"
set datafile separator ","
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set ytics font ",25"

set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "red" lw 4

show style line

offset = 0
starting_time = 37824
t0(x)=(offset=($0==0) ? x : offset, x - offset)

plot "./sar.csv" using (t0(timecolumn(1))/3600):2 every ::3 ls 1 t "sar" with lines
```

Final note: I've compiled gnuplot with the png flag. I just needed any sort of standard image format.

Comment: Hmm, one guess would be, that your self-compiled gnuplot binary isn't found when you login with ssh. Usually, different initialization file are read when using an login shell or a shell via ssh. Type `which gnuplot` in both cases to see if the very same gnuplot binary is used in both cases.

Comment: You are correct! And typing the full path out made it work.

It's odd that it doesn't source my .bashrc/.bash_profile by default though.

Comment: AFAIK the `.profile` is used (at least on Debian). So you must change the `PATH` also here.

Comment: Well it seems not to source it automatically, but I changed the call from `ssh 'do stuff'` to `ssh '. ~/.profile; do stuff'` and it works.

Comment: Does that also help with your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23813559/2604213 ?

Comment: Yes, I just retested and the problem was 100% the binary and not the GNUTERM variable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means, that your self-compiled gnuplot probably isn't found when you log-in with `ssh`. Type `which gnuplot` in both cases to see which binary is used.

Usually when using `ssh` you get a non-interactive shell, which sources different configuration files and has different environmental variables than a login shell, see e.g. [Why does an SSH remote command get fewer environment variables then when run manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216202/2604213).

So you can either change the respective configuration files (which ones are used, depends on your distribution), or you can use the full path to the gnuplot binary.